# OpenVPN connect restricted to only a specific user in a linux debian based OS

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, openvpn

I have a Raspberry Pi device running Raspbian Buster, and I want to run a few applications through an openvpn vpn connection, *but not the entire system*. So I was thinking of creating a user in the OS called "vpn-user", and then somehow restrict the use of the openvpn connection to ONLY stuff running through "vpn-user". Any apps running through any other user account should be DIRECTLY connecting to the internet.

**So is there any way to restrict an openvpn ovpn connection profile to ONLY work for a given user ?**

This makes sense for me more than only allowing vpn access for one specific application, because I have multiple applications that I want vpn access for, and I might add more in the future. By designating a user account to access the vpn, I can just tell the relevant apps to run through that user account, so they instantly have vpn access.

Answer (score 1):

Tell OpenVPN to not add any routes:

```
route-nopull
```

After bringing up the connection, add the same routes manually (or using an `up` script) to a different routing table:

```
ip -4 route add default dev $dev table 3
ip -6 route add default dev $dev table 3
```

In the same script, also add a routing policy rule to select this table for the user ID you want:

```
ip -4 rule add pref 500 uidrange 1003-1003 lookup 3
ip -6 rule add pref 500 uidrange 1003-1003 lookup 3
```

Comment: Hi. Thankyou for your reply. Can you kindly add full commands that I need to execute, like where to store the script, what commands to run, etc. ? I don’t have much experience with Linux.

Comment: FYI, I recently did what you described, and `route-nopull` didn't prevent changes in the default routing table. What really helped was `route-noexec`.